# How do I create and move a node following a given path?

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, physics

I have to create a simulation in landscape which displays a sine function and a node which moves on the given path (the sine wave). So far I've created the sine wave with a simple sine wave with it's period (2*PI).

The question is how do I create the simulation of an infinite wave and the node moving up and down ?
My code so far is:

```
(CGMutablePathRef)sineWithAmplitude:(CGFloat)amp frequency:(CGFloat)freq
                            width:(CGFloat)width centered:(BOOL)centered
                     andNumPoints:(NSInteger)numPoints {

CGFloat offsetX = 0;
CGFloat offsetY = amp;

// Center the sinusoid within the shape node
if (centered) {
    offsetX = -width/2.0;
    offsetY = 0;
}

CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();

// Move to the starting point
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, offsetX, offsetY);
CGFloat xIncr = width / (numPoints-1);

// Construct the sinusoid
for (int i=1;i<numPoints;i++) {
    CGFloat y = (amp * sin(2*M_PI*freq*i/(numPoints-1))*multiplier);
    CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, i*xIncr+offsetX, y+offsetY);

}

return path;
```

And the update method:

```
  /* Called before each frame is rendered */
self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleModeResizeFill;
// Create an SKShapeNode
SKShapeNode *node = [SKShapeNode node];
node.position = CGPointMake(x, y);

// Assign to the path attribute
    node.path = [self sineWithAmplitude:20.0 frequency:frequency1 width:400.0 centered:YES andNumPoints:70];
//node.frame.size.height

node.strokeColor = [SKColor blackColor];
[self addChild:node];
x = x+400;
```

Until now I only display a wave, but the result should move right and look like the image.
[image]

The circle is the node that goes up and down while the wave simulates too. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: add start angle to the `sin` something like: `y=sin(a0+2*PI*x/xs);  a0+=0.01; ` where `a0` is the start angle and `xs` is the x-wavelength in pixels or what ever you have on x-axis. then in some timer/redraw increment/decrement a0 by some step and redraw.